# Overlay and controlling goBack only programmatically

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I'm looking for a way to show an overlay screen that won't be closed by any hardware action and can only be done programmatically.

```
 "react": "16.9.0",
 "react-native": "0.61.5",
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
 "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
```

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61252329/edit) your question to remove "I really need this my current project please help me out. thank you!"? That information is not needed to answer the question so it's usually removed.

Answer (score 0):

quick update, react native itself ship with modal, which will help as to cover the whole screen and can be closed only programmatically.